# I'm getting 'npm err ECONNRESET' error installing React, how to fix?

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting error installing react ,
the error screenshot I'm providing below,
anyone please help me to fix this.
[image: this is error screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify if you can access https://registry.npmjs.org/ (So that you atleast see your network hasn't blocked access to the site)
2. Check your proxy server settings to verify if you have the correct ones for your environment (LAN Settings on your Internet Properties)
3. While your Company might provide a proxy which is automatically configured, the proxy configuration is not picked up automatically by terminal commands like curl, wget or npm. For curl, wget and npm to tunnel through your local proxy you have to set a bunch of environment variables:

- setx http_proxy http://localhost:[YourPortNumber]
- setx https_proxy http://localhost:[YourPortNumber]
- setx ftp_proxy http://localhost:[YourPortNumber]
- setx all_proxy http://localhost:[YourPortNumber]
- setx HTTP_PROXY http://localhost:[YourPortNumber]
- setx HTTPS_PROXY http://localhost:[YourPortNumber]
- setx FTP_PROXY http://localhost:[YourPortNumber]
- setx ALL_PROXY http://localhost:[YourPortNumber]

4. Additionally to all those environment variables then set the ff;

- npm config set proxy http://localhost:[YourPortNumber]/
- npm config set https-proxy http://localhost:[YourPortNumber]/
- npm config rm proxy
- npm config rm https-proxy

5. Thereafter a good old restart could also assist.